# Jquery mobile dual range slider reload with new range

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile

Slider works well with initial range. Here is html for slider, initial range is 0 to 100

```
 <div data-role="rangeslider">       
    <input type="range" name="range-1a" id="range-1a" min="0" max="100" value="40">       
    <input type="range" name="range-1b" id="range-1b" min="0" max="100" value="80">
</div>

<button id="btnReload" onclick="reloadRangeSlider(200, 300)"></button>
```

I want to implement a javascript function that can help to reload the slider with new range like 200 to 300. In my case, want to reload slider by clicking on btnRelaod button.

```
function reloadRangeSlider(min, max){
    //To do: reload functionality goes here 
}
```

Comment: @Daedalus thanks for your comments. I have tried now and solved the issue :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the answer of my question

```
function reloadRangeSlider(min, max){
       $('#range-1a').attr("min", min).attr("max", max).val(min);
       $('#range-1b').attr("min", min).attr("max", max).val(max);          
       $('#range-1a').slider("refresh");
       $('#range-1b').slider("refresh");         
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

According to JQuery Mobile Docs
If you manipulate a slider via JavaScript, you must call the refresh method on it to update the visual styling. Here is an example:

```
$("#yourSlider").attr("min", min)
$("#yourSlider").attr("max", max)
$("#yourSlider").slider("refresh");
```

or you can use

```
$("#yourSlider").attr("min", min).attr("max", max).slider("refresh");
```

Comment: yes thanks, you are almost here, if we call slider function together FF show "too much recursion" error, also we need to set value. and in my case what do you mean by $("#yourSlider")?

Comment: @Shahdat use id of your slider there, # denotes the id :( and if you like my answer you must have selected as right answer. and in your case `#yourslider` denotes `#range-1a` and `#range-1b`

Comment: @Shahdat why you deselect answer ?

Comment: the answer is not clear enough, more over last option was not correct thrown error 'to much recursive', yesterday I edited to make it more sense and selected as answer but once I did not see my changes, then I deselected. Let me edit again and will select as ans.