# Refreshing jQuery mobile rangeslider

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm having difficulty refreshing a jQuery Mobile rangeslider after a dynamic change of the slides values. The values in the boxes to each side of the slider change, but the slide positions don't change, and the mouse-over text doesn't change.

```js
$( document ).on( "pagecontainerbeforeshow", function ( event, ui ) {
    console.log("THIS EVENT WAS ACTUALLY CALLED");
    document.getElementById("hoursofdaymin").value = 6;
    document.getElementById("hoursofdaymax").value = 16;
    $("#hoursofdayslider", ui.prevPage).rangeslider('refresh');
    
    // I've also tried:
    //$("#hoursofdaymin", ui.prevPage).slider('refresh');
    //$("#hoursofdaymax", ui.prevPage).slider('refresh');

});
```

```html
<div class="upage ui-page-theme-a" id="mainpage" data-role="page">
    <div class="upage-outer">
        <div data-role="header" class="container-group inner-element uib_w_2" data-uib="jquery_mobile/header" data-ver="0">
            <h1>Heading1</h1>
            <div class="widget-container wrapping-col single-centered"></div>
            <div class="widget-container content-area horiz-area wrapping-col left"></div>
            <div class="widget-container content-area horiz-area wrapping-col right"></div>
        </div>
        <div data-role="content">
            <a class="widget uib_w_1 d-margins" data-uib="jquery_mobile/button" data-ver="0" data-role="button" href="#settings" data-transition="fade">Settings</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<div class="upage vertical-col left" id="settings" data-role="page">
    <div data-role="header" data-add-back-btn="true" data-direction="reverse" data-back-btn-text="Back" data-uib="jquery_mobile/header">
        <h1>Settings</h1>

    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
        <form>
            <div data-role="rangeslider" id="hoursofdayslider">
                <label for="hoursofdaymin">Hours:</label>
                <input type="range" id="hoursofdaymin" min="0" max="24" value="8">
                <label for="hoursofdaymax">Hours:</label>
                <input type="range" id="hoursofdaymax" min="0" max="24" value="20">
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

jsFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/uca97444/

Please note that I have already seen a couple of related questions on StackOverflow, but have not been able to find a solution based on these. Those that I've already reviewed are:

[Jquery mobile dual range slider reload with new range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15218183/jquery-mobile-dual-range-slider-reload-with-new-range)

[How to refresh rangeslider in jquerymobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18769524/how-to-refresh-rangeslider-in-jquerymobile)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the update with "pagecontainerbeforeshow" is too late, despite the partial change to the element.

Changing it to a "pagecreate" event worked:

```
$( document ).on( "pagecreate", "#settings", function() {
    $("#hoursofdaymin").val(6);
    $("#hoursofdaymax").val(16);
    $("#hoursofdayslider").rangeslider('refresh');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/uca97444/1/

```
$( document ).on( "pagecreate", function ( event, ui ) {
    $("#hoursofdaymin").val(6);
    $("#hoursofdaymax").val(16);
    $("#hoursofdayslider").rangeslider('refresh');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/uca97444/2/